# Read a certain line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Let's say I have a local text file called "Fruits". Inside the text file is this:

```
orange: true
banana: false
apple: true
mango: true
```

If I wanted to save what Orange is (true) in a variable, how would I do that?
Like I'd want it to be `var orange = true` according to the text file.

Comment: Are you talking node.js here, as of course browser javascript can't access local text files.

Comment: Any reason you're not using json?

Comment: @keith With require.js you can read local text file

Comment: @KevinGrosgojat  require.js, is a module loader, and like any module loader load's via HTTP, not local files.  For security reason browsers are not allowed to access local files,..

Comment: Your right, you need an apache or other http server to use require.js

Answer (score 2):

Aside from dealing with file input/output, here's a way you might parse that file after reading it:

```
var contents = "orange: true \
banana: false \
apple: true \
mango: true";

var lines = contents.match(/[a-z]+: (true|false)/g);
var data = [];

for (i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var tokens = lines[i].split(": ");
  var key = tokens[0];
  var value = tokens[1];
  data[key] = (value == "true") ? true : false;
}

console.log(data); // print results to console
```

First you create a regular expression pattern that matches each line, so when you call `contents.match` with that pattern, you get an array where each element of the array is each line of the file.

Then, you loop through the array and split each line on ": ", so now you have the two elements: the key and the value (e.g. key = "orange", value = "true").

However, the string "true" is not the same as the boolean true, so we translate the string value into a boolean using `(value == "true") ? true : false;`, and we dump those into an associative array (which in javascript is pretty much the same as an object).

So after all this is done, you can use `data["orange"]` to get the value `true`.

Comment: Wouldn't `data[key] = value === "true"` work just as well?

Comment: Yes, that works just as well! My way is just how I feel comfortable doing it. I feel like it's a little more verbose and easier to understand what it means at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your source file use Json to access data easily.

```
var fruits = {
    'orange' : true,
    'banana' : false,
    'apple' : true,
    'mango' : true };

var orange = fruits.orange;
```

You can split your fruits data in an external json file and require it in your script.

fruits.js

```
var fruits =  {
        'orange' : true,
        'banana' : false,
        'apple' : true,
        'mango' : true };
```

Script.js

```
define(['./fruits.js'], function(fruits){
    var orange = fruits.orange;
    var banana = fruits.banana;
});
```

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Out of curiosity how does this answer the question that was asked?

Comment: This propose a json structure to order data and access them.

Comment: I can see exactly what it does, but what it did - as I wrote my previous comment - was entirely miss the question that was asked.

Comment: The author begin his topic with "let's says", so i proposed an answer modifying is data file model, wich is actually text, to a json file witch is best suited for what i want's to do. 
I've not read in this question that use json is forbidden in his case.

Comment: And had you added any of that text, to explain your answer, then it would have been a much improved answer. But, while the use of JSON is not forbidden, it's also not what the OP appears to want to use, or at least is not using. If you want to propose that the OP should use JSON (a proposition I'd fully agree with) then you need to add that to your answer, not simply post a snippet of code with no explanation.

Comment: I just added explanations